# Reports deployment issue

Tags: force.com, reporting, deployment, ide

I am deploying reports from one SF org to another. I am receiving following error message while deploying report via force.com IDE (eclipse):

> Deploy Results:    File Name:
>   reports/BAR_Sales/BAR_All_Opportunities_by_Owner.report     Full Name:
>   BAR_Sales/BAR_All_Opportunities_by_Owner    Action:  NO ACTION
>   Result:  FAILED    Problem: Required field is missing: chartSummaries

I couldn't find anything on the net to troubleshoot the issue. Above issue is present for almost all the reports and the reports are too many to be manually created. I must migrate them by means of automation.

Comment: I have also tried multiple/individual report(s) migration using packages, but the package includes dependent fields, which have been migrated already. Hence, installing that package produces "Field already exist on component type"  error. :(

Comment: Did u get solution for this.

Comment: No. I had to recreate those reports in the target org. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on your Opportunity fields and see if there is one in there called chartSummaries - the error looks like it is missing in your target org.

You'll need to push up to the target org any fields that the reports use to build themselves. If you miss any out then this is the type of error you'll receive.

Comment: There is no field like chartSummaries in the source org. Already checked that.